# Scroll event listener triggering after removing the event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am using a scroll event on the window object in a component built using React. 
I add the listener in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method .

```js
componentDidMount() {
window.addEventListener('scroll',this.handleScrollChange);
}
```

Now i have a button which scrolls to a certain position on it's click event.

When i click on the button the following function fires:

```js
window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollChange);
    this.changePageUrl(currentData);
    // Add it back again.

    this.setState(
      {
       currentData
      },
      () => {
        window.scrollTo({
          top: currentTop + 100,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollChange);
        }, 10000);
      },
    );
```

Even if i increase setTimeout to `10000` , my scroll event change handler function `this.handleScrollChange` gets triggered, and the scroll event doesnt get removed.

Reading some other problems, i have already bound my function in the constructor , so its not a problem with the reference of the function:

```js
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.handleScrollChange = this.handleScrollChange.bind(this);
}
```

The replicated code can be seen here in an example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-djblfj?file=index.js

How do i remove the event listener on button click and add it back again once the `click` scroll has completed?

Comment: Are `this.handleChange` and `this.handleScrollChange` the same functions?

Comment: ah, yes ill edit the question. sorry about that, they are the same functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4b7zrj?file=index.js (Open the console, scroll to the bottom and click on the button. You'll see that the `log` will not been called even the `scroll` will trigger after that.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-djblfj?file=index.js Check this, i added some sample text, according to me scroll shouldn't trigger after you've removed the event listener and `setTimeout` for 10 seconds @MoshFeu

Comment: But that's exactly what happens. You can see that if you scroll after you click on the button, the `console.log('handleScroll');` is not firing..